# stored procedure not working after passing parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I have the following stored procedure which i am using in mysql workbench

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updateContracts`(
  p_work_contract_id int,
  p_product varchar(500)
)
BEGIN

  UPDATE work_contract_objective 
  set product = p_product
  WHERE work_contract_id=p_work_contract_id;

END
```

When i m passing the parameters p_work_contract_id and p_product, I am getting the following result and the table not getting updated

```
set @p_work_contract_id = 0;
set @p_product = '0';
call morpheus_mvp.updateContracts(@p_work_contract_id, @p_product);
select @p_work_contract_id, @p_product;
```

Comment: There is no result anywhere. Do you have a work_contract_objective with work_contract_id zero?

Comment: i am not getting any result, there is no record in  work_contract_objective with work_contract_id zero, what could be wrong here, parameters are not being passed to the procedure variables

Comment: With the code in your procedure and your set of codes, the procedure execution is irrelevant. Your procedure do an update based on the given parameters and returns or sets nothing. Then, after the procedure call you select the same variables which will result in 0, 0 as response. What was that you were expecting as result? If you remove the procedure call the select statement will return whatever you assign to those variables

Comment: one tab opens automatically with these values

set p_work_contract_id = 0;
set p_product = '0';
call morpheus_mvp.updateContracts(p_work_contract_id, p_product);
select p_work_contract_id, p_product;

Comment: set @p_work_contract_id to some value that is actually present in the table

Comment: There is no way this stored procedure won't work so the problem must be data.

Comment: The way the workbench works is to save the last used tabs. It doesn't means that whenever you open it, it will run that code in the opened tabs. You have to run it manually. I think you miss understood the behavior of the workbench.